# Ubuntu 17.10 system freeze

Tags: 17.10, freeze, gpu

I have been experiencing freezes in my ubuntu operating system for the last week.

It occurs whenever I launch modded minecraft.

I am using a Intel i5-6400 cpu, a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card and a 16GB ram.

Additionally I have observed, that the cpu usage on all four cores is at about 100% with i-nex.
Other solutions, such as the cstate solution or using an older kernel version, that I have found throughout the web have not worked.
Since I cannot shutdown the computer, even with REISUB, I have to force shutdown my computer.

I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing nvidia-346 drivers.
Apparently nouveau-drivers were causing the issues.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Adding more details as to how you solved your problem (i.e the exact kernel version you used) would have been more useful.